# How to add a span next to a simple_form label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm trying to add a span that will contain a character counter next to a label. The label is generated using simple_form, I only seem to be able to put the span either above or below the field. The snippet code I tried is below:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@message, :html => {:class => 'form-vertical' }) do |f| %>
<div class="inputs">
<%= f.input :to_user_id, :required => true, :as=> :hidden %><span id="counter">160</span>
<%= f.input :content, :required => true, :input_html=> { :class=> "field-message span6", :placeholder=> "your message goes here, keep it short, 140 characters short..." } %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form builder will have the input fields self-contained, so one way is to have the div 'input' left-floated, and then have 'counter' left-floated right next to it.

styles.css

```
input { 
  clear: both;
  float: left; 
  width: 150px; 
}
#counter { float: left; width: 150px; }
```

form.html.erb

```
...
<%= f.input :to_user_id, :required => true, :as=> :hidden %>
<div id="counter">160</div>
<%= f.input :content, :required => true, ....
```

Comment: Thanks! I am using twitter for input styling, I was floated the #counter div to the right and used the margin-right to place it in desired location.

Comment: @MichaelGreen Select (green checkmark) this if it answers your question the best.